# Excel if statement to display if anything is in the row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I don't really know how to search for this question or an appropriate title, so I hope that this will make sense.

I'm trying to construct an Excel spreadsheet to keep track of functions of a software that are currently have tests made for them. The spreadsheet looks something like below where A-F are placeholders for the tests and 1-5 are placeholders for functions.

```
|   | A | B | C | D | E | F |
|:-:|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | X |   |   |   |   | X |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3 |   | X |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   |   | X |   |   |   |
| 5 |   |   |   | X | X |   |
```

I would like to have another column at the end that would do something like this:

```
|   | A | B | C | D | E | F | Tested? |
|:-:|---|---|---|---|---|---|---------|
| 1 | X |   |   |   |   | X |   Yes   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   No    |
| 3 |   | X |   |   |   |   |   Yes   |
| 4 |   |   | X |   |   |   |   Yes   |
| 5 |   |   |   | X | X |   |   Yes   |
```

where the final column is an if statement that will display a conditional string base on if there are *any* entries in the row. I know that Excel's IF statements work something like this `=IF(A1=10,"YES","NO")` but I can't think how I would construct an IF statement that would print `YES` or `NO` based on whether there are any entries at all in the row.

EDIT: To add a little more detail. I've thought about constructing an IF statement like this: `=IF(SUM(C3:AI3)>0, "YES", "NO")` and this works essentially if I use `1`s or `0`s instead of `X` or `O` but I'd rather use the latter. Or really I'd just rather use strings instead of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:F1)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ISBLANK function.
Your solution should be something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1:F1), "Yes","No")
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work on ranges.  The COUNTA function is the way to go.